# Pitch shifting an audio file on Android

Tags: android, audio, pitch-shifting

I need to pitch shift audio files in an Android app.

The files can be in any format, as far as I'm aware.

I know for sure I can't use javax.sound. I need to try to stay away from licensed products to get this done, but I've been searching for a way to do this since Monday, so I'm open to all suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following library:
https://www.surina.net/soundtouch/
I'm using it myself presently. Checkout README to compile and there's also an example for android which works just fine .
feel free to ask any query.

Edit:Also Checkout superpowered SDK

Comment: If i've solved your problem then please accept it as the best answer.Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply. I looked into it, and it's licensed under GNU LGPL, which I cannot use.  It may work, but I haven't tried.  I'll accept since no one else answered, and I doubt anyone else will.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added another option you can check out!

Comment: Also can't use that license, sorry.  I've also been moved to another project, but thank you for continuing to try!